# How do you disable all optimizations on stack for development purposes?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Build times, using Stack, are often too high - sometimes, taking hours to build a project - for development purposes. How do you disable **all** optimizations on Stack during development, only re-enabling them for production builds?

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for: [ghc-options](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration.html#ghc-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, as epsilonhalbe points out, `--ghc-options -O0` or similar in the stack.yaml